# sql restoring database takes 10 minutes and going!

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm just restoring a small database(-5MB) but it is taking a lot of time?
Is it standard or darkness is a feature?

Comment: Try this question on Serverfault (and provide more details).

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/124972/sqlserver-restoring-database-takes-15-minutes-and-going

Answer (score 0):

You need an exclusive lock on the entire database to do a restore. If the database is in frequent use this can take quite a while.

If noone else is using the database, it should normally take a few seconds to do such a restore.